# Как отправить post запрос с данными?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Отправляю изображение на api сервиса:

```js
let img = fs.readFileSync('public/img/logo.jpg');


var options = {
    body: img,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${new Buffer.from(`api:<my API>`).toString('base64')}`,
    },
    method: 'POST',
    hostname: 'api.tinify.com',
    path: '/shrink'
  };

https.request(options, function(res,req){
    var data = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(e){
        console.log(data);
    });
}).end();
```

Консоль пишет: {"error":"InputMissing","message":"Input file is empty"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного подкоректировал Ваш код. Посмотрите, так все работает. Вы некорректно отправили в запросе содержимое файла, поэтому и вылезала ошибка

```
// Зависимости
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');

const img = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './public/img/logo.png'));


const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  protocol: 'https:',
  hostname: 'api.tinify.com',
  path: '/shrink',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from('api:<Your-API>').toString('base64')}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(img),
  },
};

const req = https.request(options, function (res, req) {
  var data = '';
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function (e) {
    console.log(data);
  });



});

// Отправить содержимое картинки на сервер
req.write(img);

// Завершить запрос
req.end();
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо! А подобное можно на AJAX реализовать? пробую так: http://jsfiddle.net/mjv1dsk7/

Comment: Для реализации AJAX запроса на фронтэнде нужно проверить поддерживает ли api.tinify.com кросс-доменные запросы (CORS)

Comment: Есть способ узнать какой сайт поддерживает CORS, а какой нет?

Comment: Самый простой способ посмотреть в консоле браузера ответ от сервера. Если сервер разрешает кросс-доменный запрос с этого домена – он должен добавить к ответу заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin, содержащий домен запроса или звёздочку *.